# .htaccess Rewrite Rule Redirects Back to Original Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I recently applied some rewrite rules in .htaccess to make my links look prettier. Everything was working fine when I was working on localhost.

But now as my website is nearing its completion I wanted to simulate it using the real domain name. I am using xampp on windows. I changed Apache conf files and added a virtual host. That virtual host is working perfectly fine. Like for example now instead of localhost my website loads from my custom domain. I changed the hosts file in windows for it to work.

But after changing to a custom domain my website is working perfectly fine but the rewrites rule are a complete mess. I am facing a weird issue, for example i have following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^login(/)?$ http://example.com/account/login [L]
```

When i type following in address bar on my browser:

```
example.com/login
```

The above link should work perfectly fine as it was working on "localhost". But instead of "`example.com/login`" it redirects back to "`example.com/account/login`", which obviously shouldn't be happening.

This is happening to all of my redirect rules, even those which consist of GETs. They also get redirected back to bare links which consist of $id=(some value).

My full htaccess file is as follows:

```
# Redirecting If Client/Server Failure Occurs
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 400 http://example.com/failure/bad-request
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/failure/access-denied
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/failure/not-found
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/failure/internal-server-error
ErrorDocument 502 http://example.com/failure/bad-gateway
ErrorDocument 503 http://example.com/failure/service-unavailable
ErrorDocument 504 http://example.com/failure/gateway-timeout

# Deny access to .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes

# Remove Page Extension
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# Remove .html-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

</IfModule>
# End of remove page extensions

# Rewriting SEO Friendly URL
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(/)?$ http://example.com/articlepage?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)?$ http://example.com/profilepage?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/preview/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)?$ http://example.com/admin/final-preview?articleID=$1&flag=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^register(/)?$ http://example.com/account/register [L]
RewriteRule ^login(/)?$ http://example.com/account/login [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not switching protocols, or mabye have a typo in the domain name somewhere? A rewrite without the `R` flag will still cause an external redirect, if the protocol or host changes.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting to just `/account/login` instead?

Comment: @CBroe i added R flag in all of of my re write rules but i am observing the same behaviour ... nothing has changed. And what to do you mean by rewrite to just `/account/login` ... actually `/account/login.php` is where my original login file is kept. I am using htaccess to remove extensions.

Comment: I meant, use a relative URL, instead of an absolute one. And I did not say that you should _add_ the `R` flag - that _forces_ an external redirect, which you do not want here to begin with. _“I am using htaccess to remove extensions”_ - then show the full thing, so that we can see where you placed the new rule _in context_. You might need to rewrite to `/account/login.php` instead, depending on what exactly you are doing, and in what order.

Comment: @CBroe just updated my question and added complete .htaccess file

Comment: So what happens when you try `account/login` as the substitution URL? If that does not work, what happens with `account/login.php`?

Comment: @CBroe `example.com/account/login` and `example.com/account/login.php` both work fine and load the page. But when i try `example.com/login` this redirects me back to `example.com/account/login` and load the login page. But i want to avoid this behaviour, the login page should load at `example.com/login` as specified in .htaccess.

Comment: _“as specified in .htaccess”_ - so did you, or did you not, make the changes I suggested?

Comment: @CBroe oh i am really sorry i couldn't clearly understand what you meant by relative url earlier ... so i tried using relative url and it is working perfectly fine  ... So why am i facing problems with absolute url